# Full width input group on bootstrap 3.1.0 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got some troubles with bootstrap v3.1.0. 
I need to get search bar that will fit entire width of the navbar like this (v3.0.3): http://bootply.com/109727
But it feels like there is some troubles with input group and I am getting that (v3.1.0): http://bootply.com/109728
Any ideas how to fix that? Or is there another way to get same result?

```
<form class="navbar-form">
    <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is the `width:auto` on `.navbar-form .form-control`. You can override this with `width: 100%` and it should work...

From the 3.1 Docs...

> As a heads up, .navbar-form shares much of its code with .form-inline via mixin. Some form controls, like input groups, may require fixed widths to be show up properly within a navbar.

**Bootstrap 3.1**

```
.navbar-form .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto; /*This is the issue*/
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Bootstrap 3.0.3**

```
.navbar-form .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: width:100% Doesn't work for v3.3.4, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 3.3.6, I solved it by using:

```
.navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn {
    width: 1%;
}
```