# Width of form elements inside an inline form in Bootstrap 3.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm migrating the application that I'm working on from version 3.0 to 3.1. The application is in an initial phase (almost a prototype) with few pages implemented. So was not expecting much trouble with the migration given that it is a minor version number update and the preliminary phase of the application.

One thing that puzzled me on this migration was that the controls inside inline forms were no longer occupying 100% of the width available.

Debugging on a browser I could notice that the `width: 100%;` property of `.form-control` class was being overriden by this:

```
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
     }
```

I don't understand much of css, but putting `width: 100%;` on each form element solves the problem although it does not seem to be the best solution. I couldn't figure out why the selector `.form-inline .form-control` was created with `width:auto;`.

Here is a fiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pasemes/Mw7rK/11/. Notice that the first element is forcefully set with `width: 100%;`. Plus, you should stretch the viewport to "unstack" elements and see the problem when the form is inline.

Anyone to help?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of your form that you're having an issue with?

Comment: Sure, was preparing one to edit the post... :-)

Comment: It looks like you don't want a form-inline but a horizontal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here! Update form 3.0 to 3.1 broke some of my forms. Learned that this is new way  `.inline-form` behaves.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

> Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by default in Bootstrap. To use the inline form, **you'll have to set a width** on the form controls used within.

Solution is not to use `.inline-form` or set width on every `.form-control` inside the form. Grid system will not help you here.

Comment: Evgeniy, from this text from Bootstrap documentation I was understanding that 100% width would be the default (even in inline forms). That is why I asked the question. Have you had a different interpretation?

Comment: Trust me, that exactly what is says.
In other words all form element have width of 100% except those of inline form, for which you'll have to set a width manually.

Comment: Open [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline), see red block of text with title which says: "**Requires custom widths**" :)

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, I don't know whether this is a proper answer, but I got back bootstrap 3.0 behavior with following project's base style.

```
.form-inline .form-control {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I borrowed this solution form the answer of same kind of problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/21471504/338986.

Comment: hiroshi, that works nicely. But is that really the new way that inline forms work now in Bootstrap 3.1? (as Evgeniy in another answer also mentioned)