# Bootstrap 3.3.0 Full width input group in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get the search box to stretch from its current position to the right and fill in the empty space? http://www.bootply.com/EafNX3XbS1

I've followed this question but it's out of date [Full width input group on bootstrap 3.1.0 navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469187/full-width-input-group-on-bootstrap-3-1-0-navbar)